# Finding Visual Studio shortcut by key?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

There's option menu to set shortcuts to a command.

But is there any way to find the command that binded with spefic key?

For example, I want to bind Ctrl + Alt + End for something.

But It's already binded with some other command and THIS is the command when I press Ctrl + Alt + End.

So I want to find the command and remove the bind.

Is there a way to do this with searching all the command list?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the keybinding section and select any item then type in a shortcut, it will tell you what is currently assigned to that shortcut, as well as giving you the ability to override it.
[image]